# How to copy a property between 2 lists of different types using declarative Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, foreach, declarative

## Context

Using a declarative approach in Kotlin, need to copy a single `name` property from `List` of `User` objects to a `List` of `UserDetail` objects based on matching `id` properties as shown below:

```
val users = Arrays.asList(
        User(1, "a"),
        User(2, "b")
)
val details = Arrays.asList(
        UserDetail(1),
        UserDetail(2)
)
val detailsWithName = copyNameToUser(users, details)
```

Models are:

```
class User {
    var id = -1;
    var name = "" // given for all Users
    constructor(id: Int, name: String)
    // ...
}
class UserDetail {
    var id = -1;
    var name = "" // blank for all UserDetails
    constructor(id: Int)
    // ...
}
```

## Problem

Tried to use a declarative approach via `forEach` iterable function:

```
fun copyNameToDetails(users: List<User>, details: List<UserDetail>): List<UserDetail> {
    details.forEach(d ->
        users.forEach(u ->
            if (d.id == u.id) {
                d.name = u.name
            }
        )
    )
    return details
}
```

This can be achieved in Java as shown below:

```
private static List<UserDetail> copyNameToDetails(List<User> users, List<UserDetail> details)   {
    for (UserDetail d: details) {
        for (User u : users) {
            if (d.id == u.id) {
                d.name = u.name;
            }
        }
    }
    return details;
}
```

## Question

How can this be done in Kotlin using a declarative approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You make too many iterations over both lists (`users.size * details.size`) so creating a hashmap can fix it a bit:

```
fun copyNameToUsers(users: List<User>, details: List<UserDetail>): List<UserDetail> {
    val usersById = users.associate { it.id to it }
    details.forEach { d ->
        usersById[d.id]?.let { d.name = it.name }
    }

    return details
}
```

Comment: Clever use of map, elegantly answers the question. Also realised another problem I was using parenthesis instead of brackets, which caused lambda parameters to not be recognised.

Comment: @SergeyLagutin you can avoid the `toMap()` call if you use `associate` instead of `map` :)

Comment: @SergeyLagutin you can even use `.associateBy(User::id)` making it even shorter :)

Answer (score 1):

An other approach with non mutable values :

```
data class User(val id: Int = -1, val name: String = "")
data class UserDetail(val id: Int = -1, val name: String = "")

private fun List<UserDetail>.copyNameToUser(users: List<User>): List<UserDetail> = map { userDetail ->
    users.firstOrNull { userDetail.id == it.id }?.let { userDetail.copy(name = it.name) } ?: userDetail
}
```

Comment: Good alternative, but less readable than the first answer. Useful for future reference as didn't realise `copy` avoids mutation.